# Is it valid to use window function with spatial functions?

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to calculate the total distance tracker traveled. However, I discovered some weird errors when I tried to use window functions with spatial functions.

If I write a query like this it is valid:

```
select
   t.createdAt,
   ST_AsText(lead(t.location) over (ORDER BY t.createdAt desc)),
   st_astext(t.location)
from track t
order by t.createdAt desc
limit 1,1;
```

Also, this is valid:

```
select
   t.createdAt,
   st_astext(t.location),
   st_distance_sphere(t.location, t.location)
from track t
order by t.createdAt desc
limit 1,1;
```

But when I try to use it like this, It gives me an error:

```
select
   t.createdAt,
   ST_AsText(lead(t.location) over (ORDER BY t.createdAt desc)),
   st_astext(t.location),
   st_distance_sphere(t.location, t.location)
from track t
order by t.createdAt desc
limit 1,1;
```

```
Out of range error: Longitude should be [-180,180] in function ST_Distance_Sphere
```

Can I use spatial functions with window functions? Is this MariaDB limitation? or Am I writing the query wrong?

Edit:

I found a very old invalid location record and I deleted it. Now my queries are all of them working fine. But I have no idea why is old record causing errors. I thought the above queries should access only the latest records.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using **ST_Distance_Sphere(t.location, t.location)** to calculate the distance between a location and itself. This is likely causing the "*Out of range error: Longitude should be [-180,180]*" error because the function is expecting two distinct coordinates to calculate the distance, but  the same coordinates are provided twice.

Please try the below query and let me know if it works:

```
SELECT
   t.createdAt,
   ST_AsText(LEAD(t.location) OVER (ORDER BY t.createdAt DESC)),
   ST_AsText(t.location),
   LEAD(ST_AsText(t.location)) OVER (ORDER BY t.createdAt DESC),
   CASE
      WHEN ST_AsText(t.location) IS NOT NULL AND LEAD(ST_AsText(t.location)) OVER (ORDER BY t.createdAt DESC) IS NOT NULL THEN
         ST_Distance_Sphere(t.location, ST_GeomFromText(LEAD(ST_AsText(t.location)) OVER (ORDER BY t.createdAt DESC)))
      ELSE NULL
   END AS distance
FROM track t
ORDER BY t.createdAt DESC
LIMIT 1, 1;
```

Comment: Distance between itself is a valid query. My second query has proved it. Your example gives me the same error.

Comment: Distance betweek the same points is always zero. Out of range is caused by invalid values (as the error message says). Longitude bust be between -180 and 180, Latitude between -90 and 90.

Answer (score 0):

1. The error is caused by a value which doesn't exist on earth. Earth is a spherical ellipsoid, coordinates must be in the range of -180 to +180 for longitude and -90 to +90 for latitude.
2. Using the result of a window function in another function is not limited, so it works also with spatial functions.

Example:

```
SELECT createdAt, ST_AsText(location) AS current_location, 
       ST_AsText(LEAD(location) OVER (ORDER BY createdAt desc))
       as next_location,
       ST_Distance_Sphere(location, LEAD(location) OVER
       (ORDER BY createdAt desc))/1000 AS distance_km
FROM track;
```